# Dúvidas ggplot em barras

Tags: r, ggplot2

Olá, estou tentando plotar um gráfico em barras `geom_bar`, onde o X corresponde a os dias do mês, neste caso fevereiro, e y refere-se ao valor de duas variáveis `v1 e v2` referente ao dia no modo `position = "dodge"`. Estudei, vi que x precisa ser um fator/date e os demais numéricos, então achei bastante confuso as explicações em sites e os exemplos tirados no stack na minha cabeça me pareceram bastantes específicos. Eu gostaria de entender se posível a lógica desse plot, vou deixar os dados para forma de ajuda e exemplo.

dados via dput:

```
structure(list(dia = structure(1:28, .Label = c("01/02/2018", 
"02/02/2018", "03/02/2018", "04/02/2018", "05/02/2018", "06/02/2018", 
"07/02/2018", "08/02/2018", "09/02/2018", "10/02/2018", "11/02/2018", 
"12/02/2018", "13/02/2018", "14/02/2018", "15/02/2018", "16/02/2018", 
"17/02/2018", "18/02/2018", "19/02/2018", "20/02/2018", "21/02/2018", 
"22/02/2018", "23/02/2018", "24/02/2018", "25/02/2018", "26/02/2018", 
"27/02/2018", "28/02/2018"), class = "factor"), v1 = structure(c(3L, 
12L, 22L, 21L, 9L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 25L, 19L, 25L, 20L, 1L, 13L, 
8L, 23L, 24L, 17L, 15L, 11L, 10L, 6L, 27L, 26L, 18L, 16L, 14L
), .Label = c("1.014", "1.382", "1.436", "1.462", "1.470", "1.479", 
"1.496", "1.572", "1.618", "1.619", "1.682", "1.692", "1.791", 
"1.839", "1.860", "1.876", "1.883", "1.943", "461", "511", "589", 
"662", "695", "735", "774", "791", "873"), class = "factor"), 
v2 = structure(c(2L, 9L, 21L, 20L, 11L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 25L, 
18L, 24L, 19L, 28L, 12L, 7L, 23L, 22L, 16L, 14L, 10L, 8L, 
6L, 27L, 26L, 17L, 15L, 13L), .Label = c("1.276", "1.301", 
"1.328", "1.344", "1.348", "1.358", "1.460", "1.468", "1.499", 
"1.515", "1.538", "1.677", "1.708", "1.741", "1.749", "1.755", 
"1.788", "429", "482", "535", "575", "646", "658", "697", 
"744", "752", "778", "924"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("dia", 
"v1", "v2"), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = "data.frame")
```

Peço desculpas, não postei nem um plot ou código, pois todos foram bem insastifatórios.

Comment: Estou achando os valores de `v1` e `v2` estranhos. Eles aparecem como fatores para mim. Isto está correto? Ou eles deveriam ser valores numéricos? E se forem valores numéricos, 1.276 significa "1 vírgula duzentos e setenta e seis" ou significa "mil duzentos e setenta e seis"?

Comment: @MarcusNunes Obrigado por ter reparado, eu não tinha.

Comment: @Macus Nunes e @MacrusNunes, falei de forma bem preguiçosa no texto, `v1`e `v2`são numéricos sim, estão ná 3° frase "Estudei, vi que x precisa ser um fator/date e os demais numéricos..." .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que para criar esse gráfico é necessário mudar a `data.frame` do formato largo para o formato comprido. Veja [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format).

```
library(ggplot2)

dados$dia <- as.Date(dados$dia, "%d/%m/%Y")
dados$v1 <- as.numeric(as.character(dados$v1))
dados$v2 <- as.numeric(as.character(dados$v2))


agg <- aggregate(cbind(v1, v2) ~ dia, dados, sum)
molten <- reshape2::melt(agg, id = "dia")

g <- ggplot(molten, aes(x = dia, y = value, fill = variable))
g + geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```

**Nota.**
Depois de ler o comentário do @Marcus Nunes editei a resposta com a conversão das colunas `factor` para `numeric`. O gráfico foi portanto modificado.

[image: Gráfico de barras de duas variáveis]

Comment: Obrigado Rui Barradas, eu sabia que tinha que transformar os dados em outros formatos, porém não sabia como faze-lo. Peço desculpas pela demora e muitissímo obrigado novamente.

Comment: @macchi Uma coisa que eu não fiz foi dar outros nomes às colunas da data frame `molten`. Assim fica um gráfico em inglês, que acho mal. E só fazer `names(molten)[2:3] <- nomes_em_português`.