# Rmarkdown Aggregate erro

Tags: r, ggplot2, markdown

Olá, estou tentando criar relatórios pelo Rmarkdown, com o método `read_chunk()` é possivel plotar no doc usando externalização de script.R. Fazendo essa integração, com apenas 1 script deu certo, quando fui colocar o segundo, ocorreu um erro na função `aggragate`, ele alega que não tem mais `rows` para gravar. Vou detalhar os passos que dou até chegar no erro:

### 1°:  Scripts em .R

Os cada um dos dois scripts contém um plot, eles são `geom_bar` da `library ggplot2`. para fazer esse gráfico, geralmente é colocado X como fator e puxar as outras informações no sentido linha como um array. Para fazer isso, usei a função aggregate nos dois scripts indicado em um questão antiga que fiz aqui no stack.

[Dúvidas ggplot em barras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/280168/d%C3%BAvidas-ggplot-em-barras)

Pedaço do script rascunhoN.R

```
dado <- data.frame("hora" = tab.genova$V1, "Mud" = tab.genova$V2, "Conf" = 
tab.genova$V3, "Alt" = tab.genova$V4, "DEM" = tab.genova$V4, "Cy" = tab.genova$V5)
agg <- aggregate(cbind(DEM, Alt, Conf, Mud, Cy) ~ hora, dado, sum)
molten <-melt(agg, id = "hora")
```

Pedaço do script rascunho.R

```
data2 <- data.frame("dia" = tab.Roma$Dia,"ResolvidosFSR" = 
tab.Roma$Resolvidos_no_FSR, "Abertos" = tab.Roma$Abertos)
agg2 <- aggregate(cbind(tab.Roma$Resolvidos_no_FSR, tab.Roma$Abertos) ~ dia, data, sum)
molten2 <-melt(agg2, id = "dia2")
```

## 2°: Código do .Rmd

````
```{r LeituraDeDados, echo=FALSE, results='hide', warning=FALSE, 
message=FALSE}
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
library(grid)
library(extrafont)
library(data.table)
library(scales)
library(gridExtra)
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)
library(knitr)
loadfonts(device="win")
# dê o set na pasta que está seus arquivos script.R, no meu caso tb os csv que eu usava.
setwd("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/testeMark")

# Esses read.csv eu uso aqui no meu pq tiro os dados no arquivo, coloquei aqui para ilustrar 
#que estou usando por este metódo e aqui no stack farei por dput (deve ser a mesma coisa).
#tab.genova <- read.csv(file="tab.genova.csv", sep=";")
#tab.Roma <- read.csv(file="tab.Roma.csv", sep=";")

```

## Plot 1

```{r echo=FALSE}
read_chunk('rascunhoN.R')
#Esse chunk está lendo e importando o script 'rascunhoN.R' com o primeiro plot
```

```{r rascunhoNplot.R , code=readLines("rascunhoN.R"), echo=FALSE, 
fig.align='right', fig.height=7.7522, fig.width= 11.816666666666666}
#Esse chunk está lendo o script importado e plotando.
```

## plot2

```{r echo=FALSE}
read_chunk('rascunho.R')
#Esse chunk está lendo e importando o script 'rascunho.R' com o segundo plot
```

```{r rascunho.R , code=readLines("rascunho.R"), echo=FALSE, fig.align= 
'center', fig.height=7.7522, fig.width= 11.816666666666666}
 #Esse chunk está lendo o script importado e plotando.
```
````

### 3°: ERRO

Após dar o Ctrl+shift+k

tem a compilação do arquivo na saída .doc, que gera esse erro:

```
 Quitting from lines 88-89 (teste.Rmd) 
 Error in aggregate.data.frame(lhs, mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : no rows to aggregate
 Calls: <Anonymous> ... aggregate -> aggregate.formula -> aggregate.data.frame
```

Vou deixar os dados e códigos dos scripts:

#### rascunhoNplot.r

```
## @knitr rascunhoN.R


dados <- #...
agg <- aggregate(cbind(DEM, Alt, Conf, Mud, Cy) ~ hora, dado, sum)
molten <-melt(agg, id = "hora")

## @knitr rascunhoNplot.R
q1 <- ggplot(molten, aes(x = hora, y = value, fill = variable))+
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity")+
  labs(x= NULL, y= NULL)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text( hjust = 1, vjust = 0.3))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),  breaks = pretty_breaks(8), sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1, breaks = pretty_breaks(8)))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.3))+
  scale_fill_manual( values = c("#8AC5FF","#73C5FF", "#73B0EE", "#5EA9C9", "#5BC5AC"))+
  theme(
     axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.3, size = 14),
     panel.background = element_blank(), 
     panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
     panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray50", size = 0.5), 
     panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
     text = element_text(family="Simplon BP Light"),
     axis.text.y = element_text(size = 18),
     axis.title = element_text(color = "gray50", size = 14, family = "Simplon BP Light"),
     axis.ticks = element_line(colour = 'gray50'),
     axis.ticks.length = unit(.25, "cm"),
     axis.ticks.x = element_line(colour = "gray50"),
     legend.position="bottom",
     legend.title = element_blank(),
     axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
     legend.text = element_text(colour="gray50", size=22,  family = "Simplon BP Light" ),
     legend.box = "horizontal",
     plot.margin = margin(15, 15, 15, 15),
     plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color = "gray50", size = 30, face = "bold", family = "Simplon BP Light"))

  q1

   #Dados:
   # ...
    dados <- structure(list(hora = structure(1:24, .Label = c("00:00", "01:00", 
   "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", 
   "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", 
   "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", 
   "23:00"), class = "factor"), Mud = c(4L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
   1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
   0L, 3L), Conf = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 4L, 
   3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 0L), AltSev = c(0L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
   0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L), DEM = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
   0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
   0L, 1L, 0L), Cyber = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
   2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = 
   c("hora", "Mud", "Conf", "Alt", "DEM", "Cy"), row.names = c(NA, 
   -24L), class = "data.frame")
```

#### rascunho.R

```
   ## @knitr rascunho.R


   data2 <- #...
   agg2 <- aggregate(cbind(tab.Roma$Resolvidos_no_X, tab.Roma$Abertos) ~ 
   dia, data, sum)
   molten2 <-melt(agg2, id = "dia")


   q1 <- ggplot(molten2, aes(x = dia, y = value, fill = variable))+
   geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity")+
   labs(x= NULL, y= NULL)+
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text( hjust = 1, vjust = 0.3))+
   scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(-0, 3000), breaks = 
   pretty_breaks(8))+
   scale_x_date(breaks=seq(min(tab.Roma$Dia), max(tab.Roma$Dia), by="1 day"),  date_labels="%d/%b", minor_breaks=seq(min(tab.Roma$Dia), max(tab.Roma$Dia), by="1 month"))+
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.3))+
   scale_fill_manual(labels = c("Resolvidos no X  ","Abertos  "), values = c("#00B0CC","#CC5200"))+
   theme(
       axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.3),
       panel.background = element_blank(), 
       panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
       panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray50", size = 0.5), 
       panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
text = element_text(family="Simplon BP Light"),
       axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14),
       axis.title = element_text(color = "gray50", size = 14, family = "Simplon BP Light"),
       axis.ticks = element_line(colour = 'gray50'),
       axis.ticks.length = unit(.25, "cm"),
       axis.ticks.x = element_line(colour = "gray50"),
       legend.position="bottom",
       legend.title = element_blank(),
       axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
       legend.text = element_text(colour="gray50", size=10,  family = "Simplon BP Light" ),
       legend.box = "horizontal",
       plot.margin = margin(15, 15, 15, 15),
       plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color = "gray50", size = 14, face = "bold", family = "Simplon BP Light"))

   q2 <- ggplot(tab.Roma, aes(x = Dia))+
   geom_line(aes(y = Meta.X, colour = "Meta.X"), linetype = 4, size = 1.5)+
   geom_line(aes(y = X._Resolvidos, colour = "X._Resolvidos"), linetype= 1, size = 1.5)+
   geom_line(aes(y = X._Resolvidos_no_X, colour = "X._Resolvidos_no_X"), linetype = 1, size = 1.5)+
   labs(x= NULL, y= NULL)+
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text( hjust = 1, vjust = 0.3))+
   scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(-0, 1), breaks = pretty_breaks(8), labels = scales::percent)+
   scale_x_date(breaks=seq(min(tab.Roma$Dia), max(tab.Roma$Dia), by="1 day"),  date_labels="%d/%b", minor_breaks=seq(min(tab.Roma$Dia), max(tab.Roma$Dia), by="1 month"))+
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.3))+
   scale_colour_manual(name = "", values = c("X._Resolvidos" = "#FFBB00", "X._Resolvidos_no_X" = "#484848", "Meta.X" = "#009600"), breaks=c("X._Resolvidos", "X._Resolvidos_no_X", "Meta.X"), labels=c("Abertos  \n    ( % ) ", "Resolvidos no X  \n            ( % )", "Meta X\n   ( 80% )"))+
   theme(
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_text(color = "gray50", size = 14, family = "Simplon BP Light"),
        text = element_text(family="Simplon BP Light"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=14),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.ticks = element_line(colour = 'gray50'),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(.25, "cm"),
        axis.ticks.x = element_line(colour = "gray50"),
        legend.text = element_text(colour="gray50", size=10,  family = "Simplon BP Light" ),
        legend.position="bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.box = "horizontal",
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())

      g1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(q1)) 
      g2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(q2)) 
      pp <- c(subset(g1$layout, name == "panel", se = t:r)) 
      g <- gtable_add_grob(g1, g2$grobs[[which(g2$layout$name == "panel")]], pp$t, pp$l, pp$b, pp$l) 
      ia <- which(g2$layout$name == "axis-l") 
      ga <- g2$grobs[[ia]]
      ax <- ga$children[[2]]
      ax$widths <- rev(ax$widths) 
      ax$grobs <- rev(ax$grobs)
      g <- gtable_add_cols(g, g2$widths[g2$layout[ia, ]$l], length(g$widths) - 1) 
      g <- gtable_add_grob(g, ax, pp$t, length(g$widths) - 1, pp$b)



      leg1 <- g1$grobs[[which(g1$layout$name == "guide-box")]]
      leg2 <- g2$grobs[[which(g2$layout$name == "guide-box")]]


      g$grobs[[which(g$layout$name == "guide-box")]] <-
      gtable:::cbind_gtable(leg1, leg2, "first")


      plot(g)
  #dados:
  #...
  data2  <- structure(list(Dia = structure(c(17563, 17564, 17565, 17566, 17567, 17568, 17569, 17570, 17571, 17572, 17573, 17574, 17575, 17576, 17577, 17578, 17579, 17580, 17581, 17582, 17583, 17584, 17585, 17586, 17587, 17588, 17589, 17590), class = "Date"), Meta.X = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "0,8", class = "factor"), 
X._Resolvidos = structure(c(5L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 10L, 11L, 9L, 
8L, 12L, 9L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 12L, 
11L, 11L, 10L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 2L), .Label = c("0,7", 
"0,76", "0,78", "0,79", "0,8", "0,81", "0,82", "0,83", "0,85", 
"0,86", "0,87", "0,88", "0,9"), class = "factor"), X._Resolvidos_no_X = structure(c(5L, 
3L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 10L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 
7L, 9L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("0,87", 
"0,88", "0,89", "0,9", "0,91", "0,92", "0,93", "0,94", "0,95", 
"0,96"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Dia", "Meta.X",  "X._Resolvidos", "X._Resolvidos_no_X"), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Isso é só a mensagem de erro, pode editar a pergunta com o código mínimo que a produziu? E os dados, são os mesmos da outra pergunta do link? (Se não forem, use `dput`.)

Comment: @RuiBarradas vou editar aqui e atualizar. Mas é o mesmo praticamente, vou dizer mais uma vez,  esse erro ocorre por ter duas funções usando o agg.

Comment: Hoje foi a quarta vez que entrei nesta pergunta e ainda não consegui entender o que ela deseja. Está tudo muito confuso para mim e acredito que para as outras pessoas que acessam o site também. Eu não sei, por exemplo, o que deve ser plotado, pois em alguns momentos o conjunto de dados é chamado de `tab.genova` e em outros, de `q1`. Também não sei como os dados devem ser agrupados. É por hora? Sugiro ao OP reescrever a sua dúvida, retirando o que for desnecessário dela e fornecendo um CMR apenas com o essencial para que a pergunta seja compreensível para quem desejar ajudar.

Comment: Vou reformular, e fazer um passo a passo. Realmente é bastante confuso de explicar por aqui, até eu fico sem entender direito.

Comment: Eu sei que é difícil e tudo o mais, mas continuo sem conseguir reproduzir o teu código. Por exemplo, quando rodo a primeira parte dele, dada por `dado <- data.frame("hora" = tab.genova$V1, "Mud" = tab.genova$V2, "Conf" = tab.genova$V3, "Alt" = tab.genova$V4, "DEM" = tab.genova$V4, "Cy" = tab.genova$V5)`, eu recebo uma mensagem de erro, justamente porque não tenho este objeto `tab.genova` em meu PC. Antes de enviar a edição da pergunta, tente rodar o código em uma instância nova do R, sem objetos na memória. Se o código rodar assim, é sinal de que vai rodar nos PCs de quem tentar te ajudar.

Comment: Tentei abrir outra instância, deu mesmo erro. Vou corrigir isso do obj tab.genova. Foi um detalhe que esqueci completamente, mas os dados referentes ao tab.algumacoisa estão nos dputs no final de cada código. Obrigado pela força.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quebrei muito a cabeça para achar o problema, o problema era o `aggregate` mesmo. De alguma forma o Rmarkdown não funciona com multiplos `aggregate` em uma instância, debugando o código verifiquei que essa função não era preciso para o funcionameto do script e que precisava apenas da função `melt()`. Então cortei essa função do meu código, usei o pacote `magrittr` para usar os %>% como  forward-pipe operator e  fiz as devidas configurações e adaptações.

```
 melted1 <- dados %>% melt(id.vars = "dia")
```

Uma dica,  o `aggregate` é muito lento, ao usar uma grande massa de dados vai pesar bastante no processamento do R (o que já não é tão eficiênte). Recomendo que use os pacotes `dplyr` e `tidyr` para contornar, vi teste em um post do stack Usa usuário provou que o `dplyr`é 20 vezes mais rápido.